# WPF - ListBoxItem alternating background and story board

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, listboxitem

for a WPF prototype I would like to accomplish the following:

I want display a listbox where each item looks like "Text Button1 Button2". All the 3 of them are bound to an Observable collection. Text displays a string, Button1 and Button2 display a double. SO far no problem. I would like to extend the functionality as follows and have no idea in how to accomplish this in the best possible practice:

1) The entries in the listbox should have an alternating background, based on the index. ie 
If (index % 2) == true, then background = red, 
else background = green. 
The index might change and the background should update automatically.

2) If the value of double bound to the button text increases, the button should be highlighted green for a second, 
else if the value of the double bound to the button text decreases, the button should be highlighted red for a second,
else the button should do nothing.

Can someone help me?

Thanke, br

// edit:
For #2 I now tried the following: Having 2 Storyboards, bound to data triggers. My problem is, that it does not highlight do each of the triggered changes Any ideas?

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="ValueDecreaseAnimationStoryBoard" Name="ValueDecreaseAnimationStoryBoard">
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            To="Red"
            AutoReverse="True" 
            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>  <Storyboard x:Key="ValueIncreaseAnimationStoryBoard" Name="ValueIncreaseAnimationStoryBoard">
        <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            To="Green"
            AutoReverse="True"                 
            Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>


    <Style x:Key="ValueTriggerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightGray" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value1Trend}" Value="{x:Static local:Trend.Decreased}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ValueDecreaseAnimationStoryBoard}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Value1Trend}" Value="{x:Static local:Trend.Increased}">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ValueIncreaseAnimationStoryBoard}" />
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: This is far too broad. You shoud first try something yourself. When you get stuck, ask a more specific question. For the alternating background, take a look at AlternationCount and [AlternationIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot,this already helped me a lot for question 1 - this is solved now.  For question 2 I'd try to accomplish this with a DataTrigger, but I'm not sure qwheter this is best practice or not. Can I accomplish that functionly only via XAML? Thanks, br

Comment: You can try for Q #2 using EventTrigger with EnterAction and ExitAction,
Where each one play a different Storyoard.
And the Event can be TextChanged for the TextBlock standing infront of the 2 buttons, in your ItemTemplate

Comment: Added comment to initial question